# Sequence in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have created the sequence function.

```
function getNextSequence(name) {
   var ret = db.counterTest.findAndModify(
          {
            query: { _id: name },
            update: { $inc: { seq: 1 } },
            new: true
          }
   );
   return ret.seq;
}
```

But when i try to insert record its give error.

```
db.counterTest.insert(
{
 _id: getNextSequence("userid"),
     name: "TestStudent"
}
)
ReferenceError: getNextSequence is not defined (shell):3
```

Where i am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: assign it to something like `f` and run it from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work only in mongo shell. You will need to insert the first sequence document to start:

```
db.counterTest.insert({_id: "userid", seq: 0});
```

Afterwards insert will work as expected:

```
db.counterTest.insert({
   _id: getNextSequence("userid"),
   name: "TestStudent"
});
```

It works for me in mongo shell. Version:

```
> version()
2.4.9
```

Comment: Strange indeed. They claim: "Robomongo embeds the same JavaScript engine that powers MongoDB's mongo shell. Everything you can write in mongo shell — you can write in Robomongo!" so maybe you should open an issue with them.

Answer (score 1):

You should run the loadServerScripts() first, and then you can use the custom function.

```
db.loadServerScripts();
db.counterTest.insert({
  _id: getNextSequence("userid"),
  name: "TestStudent"
})
```

Comment: Please do not post code only answers. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274/243457.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem using Robomongo. I solve it creating the function manually on shell.

Right-click on your database -> Open Shell.

```
db.system.js.save({
  _id : "getNextSequence" ,
  value : function (name) {
    var ret = db.counters.findAndModify({
         query: { _id: name },
         update: { $inc: { seq: 1 } },
         new: true
     });
     return ret.seq;
  }
});
```